# Unresolved Timeout Operation in Simple Asmx Web Method hosted in IIS 7

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7

I have created a simple Web Method, and I hosted it at IIS 7 in my virtual machine (Windows Vista Ultimate), as shown below

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

Then, I write a simple code to consume the web service, as shown below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       WebTest.Service1 ss = new TestConsumeWeb.WebTest.Service1();
       Console.WriteLine(ss.HelloWorld());
   }
```

The first time when i tried to used this web service, it works fine. However, it shows no luck on second attempt. In order to let the web service to work again, I found two ways,

1. restart the IIS Server, but its impossible to restart the IIS from time to time
2. Wait for a relatively long time (around 20 minutes) and it again works for only one time.

Can someone tells me what could possibly went wrong? I have listed several possibilities but I'm not sure whether they are the problems.

- IIS installation problem?
- Asynchronous web method should be used?
- Problem with IIS configuration?
- Problem with the coding?
- Something has to be done in Web.config file?

I really need your help if you could, thanks in advanced..

Comment: How you are accessing the web service using Web Reference or Service Reference?

Comment: I'm using Web reference, is there any differences on using them?

Comment: Please try to use Service Reference. That is advisable. Also try disable firewall and try to run the application to check for this problem.  Also check for Application pool settings.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I found the problem, that is the "Application pool setting", where under the "Maximum Worker Processes", by default its set to only "1", and that's why I can consume the service ONCE only, THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Excellent!!!

Comment: Good....Make this question accepted and closed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem just pointed by Mr Rajesh Subramanian

1. Under the "application pools" node in IIS Manager, followed by "advanced setting", the default value for "Maximum worker processes" is by default set to "1"
2. Changing from "Web Reference" to "Service Reference" in client side has worked charm and I don't know why, but its the solution in my case

Once again, thanks Mr Rajesh Subramanian for saving me lots of time!